# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: xml, android-activity

Hi guys I've got this problem  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.I tried to customise my own theme and then applied it to the whole application in manifest but i get that problem and the app crashes. please help. first is my manifest.xml, second is my customised xml file and the last one is the styles.xml. thanks

`enter code here`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/BashsTheme">


    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AddItems"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ViewList"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

</application>
```

```
<color name="bashs_color">#3B444B</color>

<style name="BashsTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bashs_color</item>


</style>
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: is your AddItems and ViewList classes extended to ActionBarActivity or Activity??

Comment: Yes they do extend ActionBarACtivity

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Make your **AddItems** and **ViewList** classes to extend **Activity** if your using the theme `android:Theme.Light`..

**OR**

**2.** Let your **AddItems** and **ViewList** classes to extend **ActionBarActivity** and implement the appcompat theme like `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

**UPDATE** :

in this file ...

```
<color name="bashs_color">#3B444B</color>

<style name="BashsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bashs_color</item>


</style>
```

As ActionBarActivity requires appcompat theme..

Thank you.. hope it helps.. :)

Comment: What xml files do I change mate?